# Sending SOAP request using public IP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, ip

I have Web Server on a local windows server machine with private internal IP 172.22.X.X
I want to communicate through SOAP to and external server using my public IP 151.253.X.X

My code is in C# and my problem here is that my request are going out with my private IP where as my external server receives messages only from my external IP.

How can I send/receive requests from my external IP?

Comment: How do you send SOAP requests, using HttpWebRequest?

Comment: using SoapHttpClientProtocol

Answer (score 0):

With `SoapHttpClientProtocol`, I suppose (didn't check), you can do the following: inherit from it (or from whatever class inherits from it, if you have it already), and override `GetWebRequest` method, like this:

```
public class MyProtocol : SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri) {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate += (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) => {
            return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("your external id here"), 0);
        };
        return request;
    }
}
```